# Unable to retrieve multiple column values from file in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file with following contents:

```
TIME                                                                                                                                                         

DATE     TIME         DAY                                                                                                                     
191227   055526       FRI                                                                                                                        

RC      DEV    SERVER                                                                                                                                        
RC1            SERVER1                                                                                                                         
RC2            SERVER2                                                                                                                                
RC3            SERVER3                                                                                                                                

END
```

I am fetching argument values from this file, say if I pass `DATE` as an argument to the script I am getting corresponding value of the `DATE`. i.e., `191227`

When I pass multiple arguments say `DATE`, `DAY` I should get values:

```
DATE=191227
DAY=FRI
```

But what I am getting here is:

```
DATE=191227
DAY=NULL
```

And if I pass `RC` as an argument I should get:
`RC=RC1,RC2,RC3`

The script looks below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@ARGV);

foreach my $name(@ARGV){
    print "NAME:$name\n";
    my ($result, $start, $stop, $width) = "";
    while(my $head = <STDIN>)
    {
        if( $head =~ (m/\b$name\b/g))
        {
                $start = (pos $head) - length($name); 
                $stop = (pos $head);
                my $line = <STDIN>;

                pos $head = $stop+1;
                $head =~ (m/\b/g);
                $width = (pos $head) - $start;
                $result = substr($line,$start,$width);
        }
    }
    $result =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;

    print "$name=";
    $result = "NULL" if ( $result eq "" );
    print "$result\n";  
}
```

Can someone please help me to get values if I pass multiple arguments also if suppose argument value have data in multiple lines it should be printed comma separated values (ex: for `RC`, `RC=RC1,RC2,RC3`).

Comment: So if the key has value in multiple lines, the last value is detected as the one before an empty line or before end of file?

Comment: This script doesn't apply if we have multiple lines of values for an argument. But yes I was looking for the same.

Comment: And key an values are always separated by two blank lines? And some keys does not have values, like `TIME` and `END` in your example?

Comment: Yes and ```END``` is end of the file.

Comment: Ok, but I just realized `TIME` has no value in the first block, but then in the second block it has value `055526`? So if there are multiple instances of the same key, what should the script do?

Comment: Actually the first ```TIME``` is the command. By executing ```TIME``` command I got this output file. So If there is an value under ```TIME``` then we should consider that one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, assuming the input file is named `file.txt` and the values are starting at the same horizontal position as the keys:

```
package Main;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $self = Main->new(fn => 'file.txt', params => [@ARGV]);
$self->read_file();
$self->print_values();

sub read_file {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $fn = $self->{fn};
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    local $/ = "";  #Paragraph mode
    my @blocks = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    $self->{values} = {};
    for my $block (@blocks) {
        $self->parse_block( $block );
    }
}

sub parse_block {
    my ( $self,  $block ) = @_;

    my @lines = split /\n/, $block;
    my $header = shift @lines;
    my ($keys, $startpos) = $self->get_block_keys( $header );

    for my $line ( @lines ) {
        for my $key (@$keys) {
            my $startpos = $startpos->{$key};
            my $str = substr $line, $startpos;
            my ( $value ) = $str =~ /^(\S+)/;
            if ( defined $value ) {
                push @{$self->{values}{$key}}, $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

sub get_block_keys {
    my ( $self,  $header ) = @_;

    my $values = $self->{values};
    my @keys;
    my %spos;
    while ($header =~ /(\S+)/g) {
        my $key = $1;
        my $startpos =  $-[1];
        $spos{$key} = $startpos;
        push @keys, $key;
    }
    for my $key (@keys) {
        if ( !(exists $values->{$key}) ) {
            $values->{$key} = [];
        }
    }
    return (\@keys, \%spos);
}

sub new {
    my ( $class, %args ) = @_;

    return bless \%args, $class;
}

sub print_values {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $values = $self->{values};
    for my $key (@{$self->{params}}) {
        my $value = "<NO VALUE FOUND>";
        if ( exists $values->{$key} ) {
            $value = join ",", @{$values->{$key}};
        }
        say "$key=$value";
    }
}
```

### Edit

If you want to read the file from `STDIN` instead, change the following part of the code:

```
# [...]
my $self = Main->new(params => [@ARGV]);
$self->read_file();
$self->print_values();

sub read_file {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    local $/ = "";  #Paragraph mode
    my @blocks = <STDIN>;
    $self->{values} = {};
    for my $block (@blocks) {
        $self->parse_block( $block );
    }
}
# [...]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was running my earlier script like ```cat file.txt | perl script.pl arg1``` which will take file contents to ```<STDIN>``` by default. How to achieve the same here?

Comment: I have problem while displaying the result. I am getting answer as ```<NO VALUE FOUND>``` when I use actual output file (the resulted file which I got from executing ```TIME``` command). Can you tell me what does ```(\S+)``` means? I think there is problem in splitting the columns.

Comment: It means capture non-whitespace characters. Can you send me a link to the file you used and I will test it?

Comment: It seems the blocks in the file are not separated by `\n\n+` but by `\n(\h*\n)+`